# The user does not have bigquery.jobs.create permission in project gdelt-bq

Tags: google-bigquery

I am trying to connect Google Big Query with Tableau Desktop. My steps: 
1. Allow Google Bigquery to access Tableau Desktop [image]

Step2: I connect the project: gbelt-bq/ data set full and choose the table events. Whe I press the buttom in Tableau Dsektop: Upload now I get this error message:

Der Google BigQuery-Dienst hat den Zugriff für diese Anforderung verweigert.
Access Denied: Project gdelt-bq: The user dilyana.xxx@gmail.com does not have bigquery.jobs.create permission in project gdelt-bq.
[image]

What should I do?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

You're connecting to a public project/dataset (`gbelt-bq`) that allows you to read but not write or run jobs i.e. query. You should instead connect to your own project which has billing enabled, point Tableau at it, and then read from the `gbelt-bq` project. That way you'll run queries/jobs in your project where you have access to do so.